# BAD_EXC_ACCESS with CFSocket

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm doing a small app which has TCP/IP server. I am familiar with BSD sockets and POSIX threads, but I selected CFSocket API. I wanted to do it in non-blocking/async/(very run-loop) scenario. I read a couple of tutorials and than started coding. Everything goes fine. Code for accepting connection works fine. I got 'kCFSocketAcceptCallBack' event. Things are not so good when I start to receive a data. I got BAD_EXC_ACCESS.

Code: http://www.nopaste.pl/18ka

It's my first 'hello world' app. I doesn't know very well X-Code, but it looks like "crash" occurs in internal 'select' function. My guess is CFSocket runs another thread which does 'select' all the time. Can anybody help ?

Whole project here: http://www.speedyshare.com/file/qbXjX/Playground.zip

Comment: Which line is it crashing on?

Comment: Debugger doesn't give me info about my code stack. It just complain about phthread::Select#CFSocket.

Comment: What log statements, if any, are logged to the console before it crashes? Do you have any notion of where it's crashing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the app with no debugger, then the iOS will create a crash log which will detail the state of the stack.

You can retrieve the crash logs from the device with Xcode in the "Organizer" window.

EXC_BAD_ACCESS signals typically occur due to bad pointers.